# Any record/playback utility available for IIS7/IIS7.5

Tags: http, iis

Back in the days, I used to work with "The Microsoft Playback Utility" (from Windows 2000 resource kit).

You can quickly check it out here http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/microsoft-playback-utility

Did any of you come across such utility, which works for IIS 7 and/or IIS 7.5?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fiddler can playback any requests.